# Boot images qemu on pnet

Tags: qemu

I hope you're good
I import image qemus in pnet but when I started one of the qemu, I confront this problem
please help me to solve this issue

1-I import switch viosl2-adventerprisek9-m-15.2-2017032
2-I ticked the option for virtualization for processor --->Virtualize Intel VT -x/EPT or ADM-V/RV